# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n^ke^{-an^2}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nn^ke^{-an^2}$ .

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, theta-functions

Evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n^ke^{-an^2}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nn^ke^{-an^2}$ .

I know for the special case $k=0$ , they relate to [Jacobi Theta Functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html).

Comment: inverse Mellin transform of $\zeta(2s-k) \Gamma(s)$ and $-\eta(2s-k) \Gamma(s)$

Answer (score 3):

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nn^ke^{-an^2}=2^{k+1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n^ke^{-4an^2}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n^ke^{-an^2}$

Therefore it's enough to compute $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n^ke^{-an^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

A hint to compute $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n^{k}e^{-an^2}$ for even $k$:
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n^{2m}e^{-an^2} 
=\left(-\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\right)^m
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty e^{-an^2}$$